# Matching Array than insert parent array by Index

Tags: php

hello anyone can you help me , i have 2 paramater array than i want matching , if index array 1 && index array 2 , value index array 2 push to index array 1 
can you give me tips or tricks ?

```
Array
(
   [0] => 4151
   [1] => 4952 
)


 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => BandaAceh
        [1] => Padang
        [2] => Jambi
        [3] => Palangkaraya
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BandaAceh
        [1] => Jambi
        [2] => Padang
        [3] => Palangkaraya
    )

 )
```

than i hope can use like :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => BandaAceh
        [1] => Padang
        [2] => Jambi
        [3] => Palangkaraya
        [4] => 4151
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BandaAceh
        [1] => Jambi
        [2] => Padang
        [3] => Palangkaraya
        [4] => 4952
      )

 )
```

my code so far like

```
 public function logRute($ruteoptimal , $simpanrute , $i)
{

    echo "<pre>".print_r($ruteoptimal,true)."</pre>";

    echo "<pre>".print_r($simpanrute,true)."</pre>";

    $new=array();
    foreach ($ruteoptimal as $ruteoptimalkey => $ruteoptimalvalue)
    {
        foreach ($ruteoptimalvalue as $num_key => $content)
        {
            $$ruteoptimal[$ruteoptimalkey][$num_key] = 'another string';
        }
    }
```

rute optimal is

```
Array
(
[0] => 4151
[1] => 4952
)
```

simpan rute is

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => BandaAceh
        [1] => Padang
        [2] => Jambi
        [3] => Palangkaraya

    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BandaAceh
        [1] => Jambi
        [2] => Padang
        [3] => Palangkaraya
    )

  )
```

Comment: the problem in your function is that you are never using the `$simpanrute` array. You need to check if the key(from `$ruteoptimal`) exists in that array, and if it does, you push the value. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

- first iterate through your first array
- then check if that key exists in the other array
- if they key exists, then push the value
- your final array `$arr2` should now have the values you want

**PHP:**

```
$arr1 = array(4151, 4952);
$arr2 = array(
    array("BandaAce", "Panda", "Jambi", "Pala"),
    array("BandaAce", "Panda", "Jambi", "Pala"),

);

foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($arr2[$k])) {
        $arr2[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php.

```
$data = array(
    4151,
    4952
);
$array = array(
    array(
        "Banda",
        "Padang",
        "Jambi",
        "Palan"
    ),
    array(
        "Banda",
        "Jambi",
        "Padang",
        "Pala"
    ),
);


function combine ($array, $data) {
    $array[] = $data;
    return $array;
}

$new = array_map('combine', $array, $data);

var_dump($new);
```

This should produce

```
array(2) {
    [0] =>
        array(5) {
            [0] =>
                string(5) "Banda"
            [1] =>
                string(6) "Padang"
            [2] =>
                string(5) "Jambi"
            [3] =>
                string(5) "Palan"
            [4] =>
                int(4151)
        }
    [1] =>
        array(5) {
             [0] =>
                 string(5) "Banda"
             [1] =>
                 string(5) "Jambi"
             [2] =>
                 string(6) "Padang"
             [3] =>
                 string(4) "Pala"
             [4] =>
                 int(4952)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but if the keys were to differ, it would break.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "foreach" and "array_push" instead of array_map :

```
$data = array(
    4151,
    4952
);
$array = array(
    array(
        "Banda",
        "Padang",
        "Jambi",
        "Palan"
    ),
    array(
        "Banda",
        "Jambi",
        "Padang",
        "Pala"
    ),
);

foreach( $data as $data_key => $data_value )
{
    foreach( $array as $array_key => $array_value )
    {
        if ( $data_key == $array_key )
        {
            array_push( $array[ $array_key ] , $data_value );
            break;
        }
    }   
}

var_dump( $array );
```